# MergeContent not synchronized NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

Im using MergeContent processor in Nifi to merge two Flowfiles into one big JSON Object, what I have done so far is the following : [image]
So my merge content is done using a UUID attribute

[image]

My problem is this dataflow sometimes give me only one of the two flowfiles and another problem is how can I be sure that my flowfile of mergeContent is in a fixed order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced this problem as I was also getting multiple files after merging using 'MergeContent' processor.

Then I tried with

1. 'Merge Strategy' as 'Defragment'
2. 'Merge Format' as 'Binary concatenation'
3. 'Attribute Stretegy'as Keep only common attributes
   And using this configuration I successfully created only one file in my output folder.

You can also try this hope it will work for you also.
[image]

Comment: Your merged file will be in order in which it is coming from your prosessor.You can schedule your processor using 'Scheduler' tab to send flowflow to 'MergeContent' if you want a particular order.